# Filter attribute names with periods

Tags: jq

How do I access the value of a JSON attribute that contains a period in it's name on MacOS/ Linux?

For example, I have a JSON object which has a root attribute name containing a period. For example:

```
{
    "foo.bar": {
        "one": 1,
        "two": "2",
        "three": {
            "a": "3a",
            "b": "3b"
        }
    }
}
```

On [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/) the filter `."foo.bar"` successfully extracts the value of the attribute:

```
{
    "one": 1,
    "two": "2",
    "three": {
        "a": "3a",
        "b": "3b"
    }
}
```

However, on MacOS and Linux (jq v1.5) the same input and filter (i.e. `jq ."foo.bar" file.json` produces no output.

If I add brackets to the filter (i.e. `.["foo.bar"]`) I get the following:

```
{
  "foo.bar": {
    "one": 1,
    "two": "2",
    "three": {
      "a": "3a",
      "b": "3b"
    }
  }
}
{
  "one": 1,
  "two": "2",
  "three": {
    "a": "3a",
    "b": "3b"
  }
}
1
"2"
{
  "a": "3a",
  "b": "3b"
}
"3a"
"3b"
```

How can I replicate the behaviour from jqplay.org on MacOS/ Linux so I can access attributes with periods in their names?

Answer (score 3):

OK, figured this out... I needed to wrap the whole filter in single quotes:

```
jq '."foo.bar"' file.json
```

Answer (score 0):

In the command line you need to either escape the quotes or enclose the filter in single quotes. Otherwise, the shell thinks the quotes are there to take the string they enclose as a single word.

Assuming your JSON is stored in the file `input.json`, the command line should be like:

```
 cat input.json | jq .\"foo.bar\"
```

or:

```
cat input.json | jq '."foo.bar"'
```

For this simple filter I recommend using the second way (enclose the filter in apostrophes) because it is easier to read and understand.